# Arabic first character cut-off issue

Tags: css, arabic

Does anyone knows why the Arabic first character get cut-off at every line break or edge of every lines.  I have made so many modification in the CSS to try and fix it but the first character still does not show except when you zoom the site to about 130%. its a multilingual site using Drupal but the English version of the site does not have this problem.

Comment: The question was asked here too: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38038/arabic-first-character-text-cut-off-at-the-edge-of-each-line-break-within-p-tags

Comment: is the same issue that i posted.  see the link of the css and screenshot: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nYuxMFG6BuSKy_Dsz8wa7XQay4qdsQNgSx_Om7Qt6r0/edit

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue, and i've solve it by changing the font from arial to tahoma.
i know that might not be the ultimate solution, but from some reason (which i couldn't figure after spending long hours) arial font was causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to increase the line-height of the element that contains the text.

Obviously it's hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: it does not cut-off the height but the first character at the beginning of line break.  see the screen shot link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nYuxMFG6BuSKy_Dsz8wa7XQay4qdsQNgSx_Om7Qt6r0/edit